# constructor versus too freaking many gets and sets

Tags: php, oop, class, constructor

I have a record class with 18 properties.

Before that class can be submitted to the database, all 18 properties must have validated data.

Because I'm OOP-ifying a working procedural webapp, I went about this sort of backwards.

First I addressed workflow for modifying existing records. At the time, it made sense to throw all 18 properties into the `__construct` method and avoid craploads of setters. A separate `loader` class handles the dbase business and can return either single objects or an array of record objects. That all worked ok.

**But then** it came time to address the new record creation workflow, and suddenly I needed to instantiate an empty record, except my record constructor is a hungry beast that wants 18 parameters...

...so you strip the constructor? But then I'd have to add 18 setters and call them all each time I want to work with an existing record...

doesn't seem like much of an improvement! :-/

How do *real* programmers handle this? (I'm just a weenie hobbyist...)

Comment: You don't need 18 different setters if you use magic methods. You can even have an empty object, and keep it pretty neat when you want to set all, or just some of the property's at a time. Just take a look at my answer, and expand as you see fit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either default arguments is one option, but then you have to fill out a large number of null's if you only want to use, say, the first and last.

Then again, you could do array looping:

```
private $prop1;
private $prop2;
// more properties here.

function __construct( array $props ) // `array` here is for type-hinting.
{
    foreach( array( 'prop1', 'prop2' /*, all of the props for this object */
             as $property )
    {
        // basically, this will assign all of the properties as they exist in the
        // props array
        if( isset( $props[ $property ] ) )
            $this->$property = $props[ $property ];
    }
}
```

Or, if you wanted to keep your old constructor signature:

```
function __construct( $prop1, $prop2 = NULL, $prop3 = NULL /* ... */ ) 
{
    if( is_array( $prop1 ) )
    {
         $this->array_prop_assignment( $prop1 );
    }
    else
    {
        $args = func_get_args();
        // this ensures that anything which is passed to the constructor
        // will go to the "new" old constructor
        call_user_func_array( array( $this, 'param_prop_assignment' ), $args );
    }
}

function param_prop_assignment( $prop1, $prop2 /* ... */ )
{
    //your old constructor can go here.
}

function array_prop_assignment( array $props )
{
    // foreach example above would go here.
}
```

The new version also gives you the option to simply:

```
$k = new DataClass(); // no idea what the real class name is.
$k->param_prop_assignment( 1, 2, 3 /* ... */ );
```

Comment: this seems clever, but wouldn't it basically hose any IDE hinting? the user would have to know the class inside and out to instantiate it properly...

Comment: Yes, it would. I provided an alternate method which could help out. I only thought about that after I originally submitted

Answer (score 1):

You can chain them to the constructor. Where you do this ...

`$Record = Record()->Name('Mark')->Location('A-Town, NY')->Phone('123-345-6789');`

You can do this by making a function that has the same name as your class that returns a new instances of your class.

```
function Record() {
    return new Record;
}

class Record {
    private $Name;
    private $Location;
    private $Phone;

    public function __get($property) {
        return (isset($this->$property)) ? $this->$property : FALSE;
    }

    public function &__call($property, $arguments)
    {
        if (property_exists($this, $property))
            $this->$property = array_shift($arguments);
        return $this;
    }
}

$FilledRecord = Record()->Name('Mark')->Location('A-Town')->Phone('123-456-7890');
$EmptyRecord = Record();

print_r($FilledRecord);
print_r($EmptyRecord);
```

If you need to validate some data, you can just add the function on later.

Comment: You're using __get and __set correctly in the class, but your example: Record()->Name('Mark')->Location('A-Town, NY')->Phone('123-345-6789'); simply can't work. It looks like you probably want `__call($meth,$args){ if( !count( $args ) ) return $this->$meth; else $this->$meth = $args[ 0 ]; return $this;}` That would make `$this->Name();` return the name and `$this->Name("name")->Phone();` set the name and return the phone number. Also, don't use the name of a function be the same as the name of a class. It risks dangerous instability (if it runs).

Comment: @cwallenpoole, you're right, I forgot I had to use the __call magic method to do this. Thanks for the code review! (I've done this in my projected called PRISM, and that's where I implemented the idea first.)

Comment: I got rid of the -1, but seriously... having a function and a class of the same name is trippy at best and it does invite issues if any form of reflection is ever needed (though it does not necessarily guarantee them).

Comment: I've heard many people say that the `new` keyword is syntax noise, but this is the important part on why it is there. The `new` keyword tells the parser, and the programmer what I'm doing. If I don't have a `new` keyword before the statement, then I'm calling the class, if I don't then it's because I'm calling a function. I feel that as long as your careful about that you should be fine. I'm using this in a production environment and there has been no reported issues (code used by, many, many devs around the world, at all skill levels). I also don't feel that this would effect reflection.

Comment: Also -- you don't need the `&` before __call and __get (it will actually cause problems with __get if you try to access a property which does not exist -- FALSE can't be bound to a reference).

Comment: `new` may be syntactic noise in PHP (arguably, it is noise in all of the modern, interpreted languages), but the languages which *don't* have `new` will not allow a function and a class to share the same name in the same scope.

Answer (score 1):

Stuffing 18 parameters in any sort of function is (constructor included) is bad. You'll never remember the correct order when you look at your code few months, or even few days from now on. Further more, as you experienced, when you need to extend the class it's hard.

That's why I usually prefer having classes with getters and setters. Yes it's more typing, but with getter and setters users can easily see what properties they can get and set, plus getter and setters are IDE's auto-complete friendly.

Now, the next problem is you don't want to call setters all the time when you read existing record from the database? You said you have a `Loader` class, can't you just centralize all the calls to setters in the `Loder` class?

```
class Loader{
  public function getMyObject(){
    $dbData = $this->getDataFromDB();
    $myObj = $this->createMyObjectFromDbData($dbData);  
    return $myObj;
  }

  private createMyObjectFromDbData($dbData){
    $myObj = new MyObject();
    /* 18 setter calls */

    return $myObj;
  }
}
```

So when you want to work with existing you can simply call `Loader.getMyObject();`

If you don't feel like typing out all the 18 setter calls in `createMyObjectFromDbData`, then as long as your setter follows some naming convention you can do

```
for ($dbData as $columnName => $columnValue){
  $propertyName = $columnName;
  $propertyValue = $columnValue;
  $myObj->set{$columnName}($propertyValue); /* you can't do this in java */
}
```

You may also want to add a `validate` method to validate all the properties in the object so you can call that method before you submit it to be inserted into database.

Answer (score 0):

In a perfect world your object would allow you to specify values using *either* the constructor or setters. What you could do to simplify things is provide a constructor that only accepts a subset of the 18 values and sets the rest to default values. But that assumes that there are default values that make sense, which may not be the case.

Comment: would I not then have a constructor that looked like this: `__construct($param = '', $param1 = '', $param2 = '', + 15 more)` ? or am I misunderstanding you?

Comment: Perhaps. Or you could pass a single array to it, like cwallenpoole suggests.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a lot of properties for an object and you don't want to include them all in the constructor, you can use setters return the object itself to make slightly more readable code:

```
MyClass obj = (new MyClass())
    .setName(name)
    .setLocation(location)
    ...
    .setPhone(phone)
```

Along the same lines, if all of the values need to be validated before you have a valid object, you can use a builder object to do the same thing. Basically, you create a builder object, set the values, and then tell the builder to create the actual object. It can then do the validation of all the values (including validation that uses multiple fields) right before it constructs the actual instance of the object.

```
MyClass obj = (new MyClassFactory())
    .setName(name)
    .setLocation(location)
    ...
    .setPhone(phone)
    .construct();
```